# How to run multiplayer flutter apps on multiple emulators in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-emulator, real-time-multiplayer

How can I run a multiplayer flutter gaming app in multiple emulators in android studio at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple emulator by using AVD Manager. Select Application in the dropdown in the bottom bar. Run it in multiple devices.